# Why are there start 'S' symlinks in rc0.d (shutdown) and rc6.d (reboot)?

Tags: boot, shutdown, upstart

**Start 'S' symlinks in shutdown and restart runlevels?**

Why are there 'S00-S99' start symlinks in rc0.d and rc6.d? *Ubuntu 13.04* directory listing:

**$ ls -l /etc/init.d/rc6.d**

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  29 Oct 30 12:05 K10unattended-upgrades -> ../init.d/unattended-upgrades
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  20 Apr  4 15:07 K21postgresql -> ../init.d/postgresql
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 351 Jan 30 04:58 README
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  18 Mar  6  2011 S20sendsigs -> ../init.d/sendsigs
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  17 Mar  6  2011 S30urandom -> ../init.d/urandom
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  22 Mar  6  2011 S31umountnfs.sh -> ../init.d/umountnfs.sh
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  20 Oct  7  2012 S35networking -> ../init.d/networking
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  18 Mar  6  2011 S40umountfs -> ../init.d/umountfs
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  20 Mar  6  2011 S60umountroot -> ../init.d/umountroot
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  16 Mar  6  2011 S90reboot -> ../init.d/reboot
```

As you can see, the first two scripts are 'K' (kill) scripts, which is what we'd expect in rc0 and rc6 runlevels, however the next seven scripts are 'start' scripts.

I've read the */etc/init.d/rc* script and understood that for runlevels 0 and 6 *$ACTION* is hardcoded to *stop* so, even the 'S' start scripts are passed the 'stop' command:

```
case "$runlevel" in
0|6)
  ACTION=stop
  # Count down from 0 to -100 and use the entire bar
  first_step=0
  progress_size=100
  step_change=-1
  ;;
```

Again my question is, why even bother with 'S00 - S99' scripts in the shutdown and reboot runlevels? Why aren't they all 'K00 - K99' symlinks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was wondering the same thing. See my question at [Which arguments are passed to init scripts during shutdown](https://askubuntu.com/questions/498562/which-arguments-are-passed-to-init-scripts-during-shutdown).

The reason is that all scripts in `rc0.d` are first called with `start` and then again with `stop`. This way you can order the final shutdown scripts independently of any other kill scripts to be executed during shutdown.