# Which arguments are passed to init scripts during shutdown

Tags: scripts, shutdown, upstart, init.d

I am currently looking at the startup and shutdown procedures for ubunut precise pangolin. As far as I understand at shutdown the system switches to runlevel 0 and all scripts with `K*` are executed with the argument `stop` and all scripts with `S*` are executed with the argument `start`.

Now looking at `rc.0` I can see the following scripts:

```
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root   16  1. Jan 2000  K20dhcpcd -> ../init.d/dhcpcd
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root   20  1. Jan 2000  S35networking -> ../init.d/networking
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root   14  5. Apr 2013  S90halt -> ../init.d/halt
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root   20  5. Apr 2013  S60umountroot -> ../init.d/umountroot
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root   18  5. Apr 2013  S40umountfs -> ../init.d/umountfs
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root   22  5. Apr 2013  S31umountnfs.sh -> ../init.d/umountnfs.sh
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root   17  5. Apr 2013  S30urandom -> ../init.d/urandom
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root   18  5. Apr 2013  S20sendsigs -> ../init.d/sendsigs
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root   19 26. Aug 2013  K90syslog-ng -> ../init.d/syslog-ng
```

Which means `umountfs`, `sendsigs` and `halt` will be executed with the argument `start`.

But looking at the code for example in `S90halt` I find the following:

```
case "$1" in
  start)
        # No-op
        ;;
  restart|reload|force-reload)
        echo "Error: argument '$1' not supported" >&2
        exit 3
        ;;
  stop)
        do_stop
        ;;
  *)
        echo "Usage: $0 start|stop" >&2
        exit 3
        ;;
esac
```

I.e. this script does nothing when it gets called with `start` and only actually halts the system when it is called with `stop`. I cannot find any reference to this script as a kill script, so when does this happen?

Comment: It is possibly used in some other runlevel.

Comment: @muru: I looked, but it is nowhere used as K*halt. Furthermore, calling halt (this script stops the system) does not really make sense in other runlevels besides the one used for shutdown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [Ubuntu upstart cookbook](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/#shutdown):

> Ubuntu currently employs a hybrid system where core services are
>   handled by Upstart, but additional services can be run in the legacy
>   SystemV mode. This may seem odd, but consider that there are thousands
>   of packages available in Ubuntu via the Universe and Multiverse
>   repositories and hundreds of services. To avoid having to change every
>   package to work with Upstart, Upstart allows packages to utilize their
>   existing SystemV (and thus Debian-compatible) scripts.

SystemV use run level to manage system startup, shutdown and reboot.

In `/etc/init.d` are present scripts that handles service stop/start, this scripts follow `/etc/init.d/skeleton` and are executed by the system every time runlevel change.

Run level are numbered from 0 to 6 and in `/etc` we found `rcX.d` folder, one for each level.

In these folders are present symbolic link to scripts in `/etc/init.d`, as you saw the name of this link are particular: they starts with **S** or **K** (S means start and K means Kill) followed by a **number** and the name of service.

When a system command change the value of runlevel, the scripts in the rcX.d directory are called following the **alphabetical** order: K scripts with stop parameter, S script with start. This rule does not apply to two runlevels 0 (halt) and 6 (reboot). According to [Debian Policy Manual Chapter 9 - The Operating System](https://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/ch-opersys.html)

> In these runlevels, the links with an S prefix are still called after
>   those with a K prefix, but they too are called with the single
>   argument stop.

So that's why the system halt.

This topic is very broad, I hope this little explanation is sufficiently clear.